# How to use seq() function inside ifelse statement in R

Tags: r

I am facing an issue while using the seq() function inside ifelse statement. I have a dataframe which contains the following columns.

```
Dataframe(df): newmodel    id 
               NewModel_1  30
               NewModel_2  30
```

i need to increase the id value for these 2 rows since id should not be same for a model. There is constant value(99) from which we have to increment the id values based on the condition.

When i am trying to implement the below code

```
 df %>% mutate(id=ifelse(any(grepl("NewModel_", df$newmodel)), seq(from =99+1, by =1, length.out=2) , id))
```

I am getting the output as

```
newmodel    id
NewModel_1  100
NewModel_1  100
```

Where as the expected one is

```
newmode1   id
NewModel_1 100
NewModel_1 101
```

Can someone explain me why it is happening??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: did you try creating the sequence out of mutate function as a vector then pull it into `mutate`, you had better attach a little piece of your `df` by `dput()`

Comment: (1) Never use `df$` inside of a `mutate`, it is defeating most of the "goodness" that the `dplyr` verb-functions provide. (2) Your first data sample has two different models yet your expected output is only one. I don't know which to believe.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
inds <- grepl('NewModel_', df$newmodel)
df$id[inds] <- seq(100, by = 1, length.out = sum(inds))
df

#    newmodel  id
#1 NewModel_1 100
#2 NewModel_2 101
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(newmodel = c("NewModel_1", "NewModel_2"), id = c(30L, 
30L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess is because somehow the function is getting only the first item of the seq.

You can try this way, it works here.

```
    if(any(grepl("NewModel_", df$newmodel))) {
df$id <- seq(from = 99 + 1, length.out = (length(df$id)))
}
```

UPDATE: The return of ifelse statement is only one value, so you are trying to input a vector in a single element. An alternative is to use an apply function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `ifelse(.)` is failing is that `ifelse` keys its output length based on the input length of the *conditional* vector; if it is shorter than either of the `yes=` or `no=` vectors, the extra length is silently ignored. In your case, `any(grepl("NewModel_", df$newmodel))` will never be other than length 1, so the output will be length 1.

For example:

```r
ifelse(TRUE, 1:2, 3:4)
# [1] 1
ifelse(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1:2, 3:4)
# [1] 1 4

### and for an example of how R's overly-permissive recycling can go "wrong"
ifelse(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), 1:2, 3:4)
# [1] 1 4 1
```

Here's a quick method using `match` to assign a unique integer to each of the models.

### base R

```r
dat$newid <- 99 + match(dat$newmodel, unique(dat$newmodel))
dat
#     newmodel id newid
# 1 NewModel_1 30   100
# 2 NewModel_2 30   101
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(newid = 99 + match(newmodel, unique(newmodel)))
#     newmodel id newid
# 1 NewModel_1 30   100
# 2 NewModel_2 30   101
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(newmodel = c("NewModel_1", "NewModel_2"), id = c(30L, 30L), newid = c(100, 101)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```